# How to create a local websocket server running inside a flutter application for multiplayer gaming?

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, dart, flutter

I want to create a local multiplayer android game using flutter that connects all the players through the hotspot. I tried but I can't create the local WebSocket server that listens to clients in a flutter.

So can anyone tell me how to create a web server in flutter or how to make a node js server script running in a flutter app?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Same as in plain Dart. You might need to grant additional permissions

Comment: I tried to create a board game with websockets using flutter and when I try to send data using browser it says "the remote computer is not allowing the data"